# Restrict Dashboard Users Django-Oscar (Sandbox Gateway App)

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

How can I restrict Dashboard users? I have installed the gateway app that ships with the sandbox site, but as far as I can tell, users are just approved automatically for dashboard access. Obviously this is a security concern. I have already blocked non-authenticated users from viewing portions of the site, but I need to be able to restrict/approve access to the dashboard.

The way I see it, I would have to write a custom view/form to be able to do it from the dashboard, and have the pending account registration feed to that.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Relevant code:

```
import logging

from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django import http
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context

from apps.gateway import forms
from oscar.apps.customer.forms import generate_username

logger = logging.getLogger('gateway')


class GatewayView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'gateway/form.html'
    form_class = forms.GatewayForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        real_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        username = generate_username()
        password = generate_username()
        email = 'dashboard-user-%s@oscarcommerce.com' % username

        user = self.create_dashboard_user(username, email, password)
        self.send_confirmation_email(real_email, user, password)
        logger.info("Created dashboard user #%d for %s",
                    user.id, real_email)

        messages.success(
            self.request,
            "The credentials for a dashboard user have been sent to %s" % real_email)
        return http.HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('gateway'))

    def create_dashboard_user(self, username, email, password):
        user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()
        return user

    def send_confirmation_email(self, real_email, user, password):
        msg = get_template('gateway/email.txt').render(Context({
            'email': user.email,
            'password': password
        }))
        send_mail('Dashboard access to Oscar sandbox',
                  msg, 'blackhole@latest.oscarcommerce.com',
                  [real_email])
```

https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/sites/sandbox/apps/gateway/views.py
This just automatically creates an is_staff user, as long as the email is valid.

Comment: One thought I had was restricting the dashboard page to an already authenticated user, marked as is_staff. Seems clumsy though

Comment: Have you looked at the relevant [doc on dashboard permissions](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/apps/dashboard.html?highlight=dashboard)? The bundled sandbox app is [an example site for exploring oscar](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/sandbox.html?highlight=sandbox), but does not really fit all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution I eventually used was to restrict gateway access to superusers. As the app already uses the

```
django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware
```

It has access to the user model.
I placed an if block in the gateway email request template `form.html`:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if user.is_superuser %}
    <email form>
    {% else %}
    <insufficient user privileges partial template>
    {% endif %}
    <not logged in partial template> 
{% endif %}
```

Similarly for the retail access, I used

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if user.is_staff%}
    <email form>
    {% else %}
    <insufficient user privileges partial template>
    {% endif %}
    <not logged in partial template> 
{% endif %}
```

This way, only superusers can create staff members, and both staff members and superusers can create retail accounts.